# Method to find 'principal components' of EMG recordings of reflexes

Tags: pca, matlab, dimensionality-reduction, signal-processing, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I have a series of electromyographic (EMG) reflex recordings, of which I would like to find out the principal components. My thoughts are that there are multiple processes that added together result in the EMG recording.

Here is a series of reflexes of a single recording [image: series of reflexes]
and here a single reflex [image: single reflex]

As you can see all reflex responses are stimulus time-locked and have clear a beginning and end (Note the vertical line is the detected latency in does not belong to the recording).

I already tried to apply a principal components analysis (PCA) and got good results but there are negative factor loadings, which I can not easily explain physiologically. A non-negative matrix factorization (NNMF) does not allow negative input values so I offset the the signal to be strictly positive. I think both methods deliver, on first sight, good results, but how interpretable are they in the sense of multiple processes adding up to the compound EMG signal.

My questions now are: Which method should I use? Are there better methods than PCA and NNMF for this task and can I just offset the values for NNMF.

Thanks in advance and please let me know if I should explain something in more detail.

--
Edit:
Here is a sample result of the NNMF with two factors
[image: sample result]
The upper figure shows the two components and the lower image the factor loadings for each response in the series. What can be seen is that at the start of the stimulation the green factor is more present and is 'replaced' between the 10th and 15th response with the blue one.

Edit2:
NNMF seems to only return correct results for rectified responses. Is there a method to restrict PCA for non-negative loadings?

Comment: Can you clarify what your actual goal is? If I got you correctly, it is to somehow find the different components that lead to the signal. You are in a sense seeking a different representation of the signal which lets you see what is going on more easily. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. The thought is that the recording of one reflex consists of multiple primitives that correspond to different motor pools being activated. We want to describe a series of repetitively elicited reflexes according to the weight of the primitives.
The problem is that negative factor loadings are hard, if not impossible, to interpret as a physiological process and that the sign of the signal should be preserved.

Comment: So the contribution of each primitive should be nonnegative?

Comment: Yes, the primitives can contain positive and negative values but to reconstruct the 'original' signal from the primitives each primitive can only be multiplied by a non-negative value.

Comment: Ok. So I believe that NMF is the right way to go then. If you want more powerful models, you can try Kernel NMF, with which I have no experience. You might also want to try restricted Boltzmann machines, which have Bernoulli distributed latent variables (and are thus 0-1, but the values in btw work in practice as well). Also, you might want to try members of the auto encoder family with sigmoidal activation functions, which will have the property you desire as well. (If you need references, let me know.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will check those methods out. NMF has the problem that it cannot handle input that has negative values, do the other methods overcome this problem? I think if I could restrict the PCA for non-negativ factor loadings it would be ok too.

Comment: These methods can deal with it. I don't see how you would restrict PCA in that way, but an auto encoder is essentially PCA with a non linearity in between (which can make sure that all values are non negative) tained with gradient descent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I now have some more reading and experimenting to do.

Answer (score 2):

I have some experience with finding correlations between EMG signals and human kinematics. When doing that it is crucial to full wave rectify the signal, which means nothing more than to take the absolute value.

The reason for this is that EMG signals are potentials, so the integral will be zero. If you then sum them up, they will be roughly zero. This might result in some models to not be able to learn anything if they cannot mimic taking the absolute value. (I am rather handwavy in the last paragraph, but I know for sure that rectifying improved performance from basically failing to something usable in my case.)

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I think I have not expressed myself clearly. This kind of EMG recording is special in the sense that every stimulus results in EMG response that is in a clear relation to the stimulus. Thus if I want to compare the discrete responses with each other I can create time-windows that are related to the stimulus time and don't need to rectify. Also not only the amount of response is important but also the shape and directionality. All responses look similar to the one in the second figure. 
Please correct my if I am wrong and thanks again